# Position in list scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm not sure how to do this and couldn't find an example of it anywhere. How do I find the position of a value in a list. For example I have a `(define findValue x lst)` which accepts a value and list and from that list I want type in `(findValue 3 '(1 2 0 8 5 6))` and it should return 0 since the value in position 3 is 0. From my understanding and how it usually is position 3 would be 8 and not 0 in arrays at least. How does it work in here and how do I approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(define (at n xs)
    (cond ((null? xs) xs)
          ((= n 1) (car xs))
          (else (at (- n 1) (cdr xs)))))
```

Use it as follows:

```
(at 3 '(1 2 0 8 5 6)) => 0
```

For zero-based indexing change the `(= n 1)`  check on the 3rd line to `(= n 0)`.

**Edit:** So you want to partially apply the `at` function?  All you need is `curry` and `flip`. They are defined as follows:

```
(define (curry func . args)
    (lambda x (apply func (append args x))))

(define (flip func)
    (lambda (a b) (func b a)))
```

Using `curry` and `flip` you can now partially apply `at` as follows:

```
(define position (curry (flip at) '(1 2 0 8 5 6)))
```

You can now use `position` as follows:

```
(position 3) => 0
(position 4) => 8
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks! Makes more sense now, I didn't realize the n controls the indexing.

Comment: Ok I might as well ask you in case you understand this better than me. I'm trying to put this into a function which returns a function type of thing. So for example calling `(position 3)` would return the same as the original problem. I understand the simple function which returns another function but I can't get a grasp around this one as easily.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It this what you wanted to do?

Comment: Yes you're right, I figured it out a few days ago, it was simply just adding lambda and having another function in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually indexes are counted starting from `0`, and your understanding is correct. But if you're required to implement a `findValue` procedure that starts counting indexes from `1`, it's not that hard to write the procedure:

```
(define (findValue idx lst)
  (cond ((or (null? lst) (negative? idx)) #f)
        ((= idx 1) (car lst))
        (else (findValue (sub1 idx) (cdr lst)))))
```

Explanation:

- If the list received as parameter is empty or the index becomes negative, we treat that as a special case and return `#f` to indicate that the value was not found
- If the index is `1` then we're right where we wanted, so it's time to return the current element
- Otherwise advance the recursion: subtract one from the index and advance one position over the list

It works as expected:

```
(findValue  3 '(1 2 0 8 5 6))
=> 0
(findValue -1 '(1 2 0 8 5 6))
=> #f
(findValue  7 '(1 2 0 8 5 6))
=> #f
```

Comment: So basically you're forcing the index to start at 1? So if I put `((= idx 2))` It'll start the indexing at 2? Never did that to anything else so that's different.

Comment: @user2318083 yes, in a way we're stating that an index of `1` is where we want to start counting. And beware, you also have to take into account the cases where the list is empty before we reach the desired index, or if the index is negative.